# Lazy loading of UI elements / IBOutlets

Tags: ios

I have some UI elemets (UIViews, labels and a datapicker)  created in Storyboard that I only want to initialise if the user press a UIButton: I currently just hide and unhide it...lol.  It woks fine, but not ideal I guess, surely there is a better way.  Is it for example possible to load IBOutlets lazily.. i.e. only if they are needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Basically when a view is instantiated, all controls in it are created and all IBOutlets are wired as part of setting it up.

What you need to delay the creation of parts of your view until you need them. Both the controls and the wiring. You will need to extract those controls out to a separate view, storyboard or xib file and use code to load them. You can manually add views, or perhaps you can manually use an embedded segue. Another alternative is custom controls.

But I'm guessing that from you description that all this is overkill and your app is actually quite happy as it is.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I think I will implement one of your suggestions if I notice issues.  I just felt that hiding was a bit hacky, but will have to do for now.  Thank you !